# Query that gets some specified data from database

Tags: mysql, database

I have two mysql database tables 'delivery rows' and 'delivery rows report'

delivery_rows table has two columns: deliver_id and article_type

delivery_rows_report table has three columns: id, errors, service_time

how do i write the query that gets : number of errors per article type ?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `id` in `delivery_rows_report` is related to `deliver_id`, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(drr.errors) FROM delivery_rows dr INNER JOIN delivery_rows_report drr ON drr.id=dr.deliver_id GROUP BY dr.article_type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delivery_rows - deliver_id | article_type
delivery_rows_report - columns: id | errors | service_time
```

Mysql query will be

```
SELECT count(a.errors) FROM delivery_rows a, delivery_rows_report b
WHERE a.delivery_id = b.id 
GROUP BY a.article_type
```

This will give you Number of errors in each article type